# Preload Text/Decimal % Percent Counter Only

Tags: javascript, image, progress-bar, counter, preload

I have a script that works wonderfully for preloading my images, and the progress bar works wonderfully right along with it.

I need the percentage counter w/it.
Can it be integrated into this existing script?

It currently shows a static "0%". If I cannot add to this script and have it auto calculate 0% to 100% when complete, then I will just delete the 0% altogether.

Here's the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/flipflopmedia/5fpk4a0c/5/

```
<head>

<title>Preload Image Page</title>

<script>

// You may modify the following:
var locationAfterPreload = "http://www.google.com" // URL of the page after preload finishes
var lengthOfPreloadBar = 150 // Length of preload bar (in pixels)
var heightOfPreloadBar = 15 // Height of preload bar (in pixels)
// Put the URLs of images that you want to preload below (as many as you want)
var yourImages = new Array(
    "http://www.safarivet.com/wp-content/themes/safarivet/images/careers/imagemap/Safari_Career_Path.png",
    "http://www.safarivet.com/wp-content/themes/safarivet/images/careers/imagemap/Safari_Career_Path_with_Rollovers_ani-2-new.gif"
)

// Do not modify anything beyond this point!
if (document.images) {
var dots = new Array() 
dots[0] = new Image(1,1)
dots[0].src = "http://www.safarivet.com/wp-content/themes/safarivet/images/careers/imagemap/preload_black_bar.gif" // default preloadbar color (note: You can substitute it with your image, but it has to be 1x1 size)
dots[1] = new Image(1,1)
dots[1].src = "http://www.safarivet.com/wp-content/themes/safarivet/images/careers/imagemap/preload_blue_bar.gif" // color of bar as preloading progresses (same note as above)
var preImages = new Array(),coverage =  Math.floor(lengthOfPreloadBar/yourImages.length),currCount = 0
var loaded = new Array(),i,covered,timerID
var leftOverWidth = lengthOfPreloadBar%coverage
}
function loadImages() { 
for (i = 0; i < yourImages.length; i++) { 
    preImages[i] = new Image()
    preImages[i].src = yourImages[i]
}
for (i = 0; i < preImages.length; i++) { 
    loaded[i] = false
}
checkLoad()
}
function checkLoad() {
if (currCount == preImages.length) { 
    location.replace(locationAfterPreload)
    return
}
for (i = 0; i <= preImages.length; i++) {
    if (loaded[i] == false && preImages[i].complete) {
        loaded[i] = true
        eval("document.img" + currCount + ".src=dots[1].src")
        currCount++
    }
}
timerID = setTimeout("checkLoad()",10) 
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<center>
<p>
Please be patient while some images<br>
are being preloaded...
</p>
<p>
0%
<script>
// It is recommended that you put a link to the target URL just in case if the visitor wants to skip preloading
// for some reason, or his browser doesn't support JavaScript image object.
if (document.images) {
var preloadBar = ''
for (i = 0; i < yourImages.length-1; i++) {
preloadBar += '<img src="' + dots[0].src + '" width="' + coverage + '" height="' + heightOfPreloadBar + '" name="img' + i + '" align="absmiddle">'
}
preloadBar += '<img src="' + dots[0].src + '" width="' + (leftOverWidth+coverage) + '" height="' + heightOfPreloadBar + '" name="img' + (yourImages.length-1) + '" align="absmiddle">'
document.write(preloadBar)
loadImages()
}
document.write('<p><small><a href="javascript:window.location=locationAfterPreload">Skip    Preloading</a></small></p>')
</script>
</p>
</center>
```

In a real environment, it will redirect to the page of my choosing after everything has preloaded. That part of the script does not work in the fiddle, so do not concern yourself with that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ran into a separate issue with this. It only allows preloading of 150 images. Once I add 151, the progress bar length shortens to 1/4 of original size?

Comment: No one??? :( Was hoping someone would have an answer on the percentage counter part of this? Not concerned at all with the amount of images I can load, I omitted the small images so the latter (last comment) is not an issue.